# How to design the right structure of Angular components?

Tags: angular

I have installed Angular using CLI, with a standard structure.  Entry point to application is `app.module` by default.

```
app.module -> app.component
```

In the template `app.component.html`:

```
<router-outlet>
</ router-outlet>
```

This template should be visible only after authorization.

The problem is that when I request an authorization page (login page), it is inserted into this private template. What is wrong? The login page should work as a separate page.

How to organize it?

Problem is described in pic:

[image]

Comment: Why should the template of your root component, which doesn't contain anything sensitive, be only visible after authorization? Where would anything be displayed if the root component template can't be displayed?

Comment: I have private SPA, first page always login page. It is separate page. Others it is admin part

Comment: That is quite unclear, and doesn't answer my questions. What are you trying to achieve, and why shouldn't the app component template, which doesn't contain anything other than the router outlet, be hidden?

Comment: I have public login page. Others are private and available after login. I did not get your answer

Comment: So what you want to keep private and inaccessible before login is not your root component. It's all the page components except the login page component

Comment: I think it should be two different pages with two route-outlet

Comment: Yes, main page is login page by default.

Comment: If you can provide please structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to keep private before login is not your root component. What you want to keep private is all the page components except the login component.

So you simply need a route configuration like the following:

```
[
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard], 
    children: [
        all your other pages here
    ]
  }  
]
```

And the AuthenticatedGuard should prevent the activation and navigate to the login route if the user is not authenticated yet.

Regarding the second part of your question. the problem is that your root component template contains much more than what you claim in the first part: it contains a left menu in addition to the router outlet. Remove that from the root component, since you don't want that side bar on all of the pages: the login page shouldn't have it. Instead, put it in a separate  "sub-root" component, that we'll call the main component. This component should have the left menu, and a (second) router-outlet in its template.

```
 [
  { 
    path: 'login', 
    component: LoginComponent 
  },
  { 
    path: '', 
    canActivate: [AuthenticatedGuard], 
    component: MainComponent,
    children: [
      // all your page components here
    ]
  }  
]
```

An alternative would be to keep it as in the first part of the answer, and to simply add an `*ngIf` on the left menu to test if the user is authenticated or not.

Comment: Yes, but problem in `route-outlet` I will provide pic in question

Comment: I have added pic, problem is that I have template HTML in app.component.html. It is private part. When I open login page it shows login template inside private part.

Comment: So, you recommend move skeleton of template to MainComponent.html? And leave route-outlet in AppComponent.html as main?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "leave route-outlet in AppComponent.html as main".  The app component, being the root component, is displayed whatever the route is. So its template should contain what is common to **all** the pages, including the login page. Since the menu shouldn't be in the login page, it must not be in the app component template. The main component is the parent component of all the pages except the login page, so that's where the menu should be. Both the app component and the main component must have a router-outlet, since they both have child routes.

Comment: I got you, I meant app.component must contain only route-outlet in my case?